# Error on Like Operator

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

```
Select * From menu 
WHERE menu_item_desc LIKE ‘kids%’;
```

On this statement I am getting an error saying to check the syntax to use near '%' LIMIT 0,30' at line 2. No idea whats wrong.

Comment: I don't see the ```LIMIT 0, 30``` anywhere in your statement.

Comment: MyPHPAdmin. It's for a class, sorta basic intro class.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're using a unicode left-single-quote and right-single-quote character to surround `kids%`. You need to use actual single quote characters, or you'll get the syntax error you've noticed.

```
Select * From menu 
WHERE menu_item_desc LIKE 'kids%';
```